# Warmth of a seat that has been vacated by a person who was sitting on it

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, slang

I fail to recall this word (could be informal in nature) that refers to the *'warmth of a seat that has just been vacated by someone seated on it for some time'*.

Anyone?

Comment: The best that I can come up with is 'butt-print', which I'm quite sure isn't exactly the answer.

Comment: Sounds like something the Romans might've had a word for...

Comment: Shoeburyness (Adams, Lloyd)

Comment: @z7sgѪ that is an answer, not a comment!

Comment: Shoeburyness is close, but its actual definition is 'The vague uncomfortable feeling you get when sitting on a seat which is still warm from somebody else's bottom.' So the feeling rather than the warmth.

Comment: I usually just call it the warm spot.

Comment: Or perhaps "posterior memory."

Answer (score 2):

Let me go ahead and coin "posterior thermoresidual."

Answer (score 2):

*Urbandictionary* has the following slang terms:

> **[*Man Heat*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=manheat)**
>
> The residual warmth left over on a toilet seat after a man or woman has taken a crap, and or mearly sat there undressed for a period of time. The life force that sustains warm seat warriors.
>
> *When I sat down on the bowl I was pleasently surprised (disgustingley horrified) by the residual man heat left by my roommate.*

---

> **[*Post-rectal warmth*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Post-rectal%20warmth)**
>
> The uncomfortable warm feeling you get after sitting in a seat that was previously occupied by a "fluffy" person with a huge butt.
>
> *"Ewww, that lard butt left post-rectal warmth in my seat!"*

---

> **[*ass heat*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ass%20heat)**
>
> The residual warmth on a chair or toilet seat from someone else's butt.
>
> *I sat down on the throne in stall 2 and I knew that Carl had just been there from all the ass heat.*

[image]

<sub><sup>Image source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne6RT.jpg</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

**Thermal buttprint**, akin to [thermal handprint](https://www.google.com/search?q=thermal+handprint&tbm=isch).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where I'm from we call it Firepad, although that typically assumes the person who was formerly sitting in the chair farted as well.